# How to show push notification badge count on app icon in android programmatically?

Tags: android, push-notification

[image]I am very new to android app development and now I am trying to add push notification badge count over App icon in one of my app which will run on different manufacturers devices. But I am unable to do this, I googled it, but I did not get any satisfactory answer which can solve my issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do your consider your "App icon" to be?

Comment: I have edited and added an image, so I want a badge count like this in my app.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in Android for this. A few device manufacturers and home screen makers offer this, though I am not aware that any have a documented and supported API for it.